# Why Do I Get Function Errors In My Script?

Tags: function, roblox

I watched a YouTube video on how to make a donate button in Roblox and followed the steps. But then when I used it, it gave me multiple errors.

I have tried changing `.connect` to `:Connect` but it gave me more errors, I tried changing `end)` to `end`, but it gave me more errors.

**Code:**

```
local id = 459818680

script.Parent.TextButton.MouseButton1Click.connect()(function()
game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptProductPurchase            
(game.Players.LocalPlayer, id)
end)
```

I expected to be able to click on it when I tested it and a menu for a purchase would pop up. Nothing happened. I also got errors like this:

> Players.ImNotKevPlayz.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.LocalScript:4: bad argument #1 to 'connect' (RBXScriptSignal expected, got no value)

When I tried the debug command in Roblox commands, it gave me this error:

> Error in script: '=' expected near ''

Comment: Can you post the errors you got? Also a Minimal, Complete, and verifiable example of the code if you can, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did include the errors I got though..

Comment: You said it gave you errors, and then you changed something which have you more errors. I don't recall you saying what errors you got from doing what. That's all I was trying to say :D

Comment: I got this error when I changed .connect to :Connect Players.ImNotKevPlayz.PlayerGui.LocalScript:5: ambiguous syntax (function call x new statement) near '(' and when I tryed the script again doing the end instead of end) nothing happened. I'm pretty sure roblox updated their scripts so this script might be outdated. I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyo, your script almost works, it just looks like you've just got some syntax errors.

```
bad argument #1 to 'connect' (RBXScriptSignal expected, got no value)
```

This means that the [MouseButton1:Connect](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/event/GuiButton/MouseButton1Click) function was expecting an argument, but you didn't give it anything.

Try out this fix :

```
local id = 459818680
local targetButton = script.Parent.TextButton
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")

targetButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function() --  <-- this just needed to be fixed
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    MarketplaceService:PromptProductPurchase(player, id)
end)
```

Comment: Nope, got these errors
     TextButton is not a valid member of TextButton

Comment: or this TextButton is not a valid member of ScreenGui

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new I don't really know how to edit stuff.

Comment: Is this error pointing at the assignment of local targetButton? The assumption that this script makes is that you have put this script as a child of some object, and that object also has a TextButton in it named "TextButton".
Did you rename the TextButton to something else?

Comment: Oh I changed the name to something else.